# Creating a disk-based data structure

Tags: python, file, data-structures, disk

I couldn't find any resources on this topic. There are a few questions with good answers describing solutions to problems which call for data stored on disk (pickle, shelve, databases in general), but I want to learn how to implement my own.

1) If I were to create a disk based graph structure in Python, I'd have to implement the necessary methods by writing to disk. But how do I do that?

2) One of the benefits on disk based structures is having the efficiency of the structure while working with data that might not all fit on memory. If the data does not fit in memory, only some parts of it are accessed at once. How does one access only part of the structure at once?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a number of problems you have to solve, some are quite straight forward and some are a little bit more elaborate, but since you want to do it yourself I don't think you minding about filling out details yourself (so I'll skip some parts).

First simple step is to serialize and deserialize nodes (in order to be able to store on disk at all). That could be done in an ad hoc manner by having your nodes having an `serialize`/`deserialize` method - in addition you might want to have the serialized data to have an type indicator so you can know which class' `deserialize` you should use to deserialize data. Note that on disk representation of a node must reference other nodes by file offset (either directly or indirectly).

The actual reading or writing of the data is done by ordinary (binary) file operations, but you have to seek to the right position in the file first.

Second step is to have the possibility to allocate space in the file. If you only want to have a write-once-behaviour it's quiete forward to just grow the file, but if you want to modify the data in the file (adding and removing nodes or even replacing them) you will have to cope with situation where regions in the file that are no longer in use and either reuse these or even pack the layout of the file.

Further steps could involve making the update atomic in some sense. One solution is to have a region where you write enough information so that the update can be completed (or abandoned) if it were terminated prematurely in it's most simple form it might just be a list of indempotent operations (operation that yields the same result if you repeat them, fx writing particular data to a particular place in the file).

Note that while (some of) the builtin solutions does indeed handle writing and reading the entire graph to/from disk they do not really handle the situation where you want to read only part of the graph or modifying the graph very efficient (you have to read mostly the whole graph and writing the complete graph in one go). Databases are the exception where you may read/write smaller parts of your data in a random manner.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with something [simple](https://gist.github.com/miku/cc492fab210b8fcd4004). Let's say you store your graph in a dictionary:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# coding: utf-8

def read(filename):
    """
    Read a graph from a file. Returns a dictionary.
    The file must be in the format:

    SRC DST DST ...
    SRC DST
    ...

    where SRC and DST are names of nodes.
    Node names must not contain whitespace.
    """
    g = {}
    with open(filename) as handle:
        for line in handle:
            line = line.strip()
            if line == "":
                continue
            parts = line.split()
            src, targets = parts[0], parts[1:]
            if src not in g:
                g[src] = set()
            for target in targets:
                g[src].add(target)
    return g

def write(filename, g):
    """ Write dictionary `g` to file. """
    with open(filename, "w") as handle:
        for src, targets in g.iteritems():
            handle.write("%s %s\n" % (src, " ".join(targets)))
```

Example usage:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = {
        "A": ["B", "C"],
        "B": ["D"],
        "C": ["B"],
    }
    write("test.g", g)
    g = read("test.g")
    print(g) # {'A': set(['C', 'B']), 'C': set(['B']), 'B': set(['D'])}
```

The above *defines* a simple serialization format for a graph and implements read and write methods. While really inefficient, you can create, update and alter graphs and persist them to disk with these two methods alone.

This will store the whole graph in memory. As a next optimization, you could write methods - e.g. `read_node(filename, nodename)` that would only load a given node into memory. In this way, you could store and work with graph larger than the memory available.

This is of course still very inefficient, since you would need to read the whole file to find the node, that you are looking for.

You could then add further optimizations, e.g. store the data sorted and use binary search to find nodes with a given name quickly. Or you store additional data along the graph data for indexing purposes. You could load a small index into memory, lookup the nodes you care about and then seek to the position, where the data is stored and read only the relevant chunks.

And so on. After a lot of exploration you might arrive at more advanced data structures like [B-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), [Log-structured merge-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-structured_merge-tree) or [inverted indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index).